# Would this be possible using Craft Pro?

Tags: assets

I'm building a large social media site. We've already coded user registration and  profiles using Code Igniter.

Situation 1:

a) We'd like to offer each user their own blog. We envision using a single template which they could customize with their own header image. Is it possible create new blogs using the API and bypass the Craft login process so the user goes straight to their dashboard?

b) Do you think it would be possible to have posts 'repostable' by other users, so the post from one blog appears on another?

Situation 2:

a) We are going to have channels of content such as games. Within those channels are hubs for individual games such as Grand Theft Auto. Each hub will have multiple section such as news (user submitted articles, videos, media), galleries, Q&A and forums. Each hub will not be owned by any particular user - they can only submit content to it. Is this something that could be powered by Craft, or better suited to Expression Engine?

b) We will also have main channel pages with articles submitted by paid users. Was planning on using Expression Engine for that.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a great "question"... It's far too broad, containing several actual questions. It's a hypothetical "what if?" about a business decision. It's hard to foresee how any answers generated by this question would be of future value to anyone else.

Comment: If you are considering Craft CMS for this build, I suggest contacting support@buildwithcraft.com to ensure your use-case falls within their license agreement. Better to be safe :)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, virtually anything is possible with Craft Pro.** If it's something another CMS can do, then there is a 99.9% chance that Craft can do it, and do it well.

In order to prevent a jumbled mess of answers, please break your question up into its various components. Ask each question individually, and you will get much better responses. :)